# Callback buffer was too small! (OpenCV)

Tags: java, android, opencv

I've been trying to get a very basic OpenCV based app to work (at this moment in time, it only takes in an input from the camera). However, I keep coming across this error:

```
E/Camera-JNI﹕ Callback buffer was too small! Expected 1382400 bytes, but got 608256 bytes!
```

My main gripe with this seemingly arcane error is that the OpenCV samples work on my phone (Galaxy S3, running CM10.2 (Android 4.3.1). My code is pretty much a carbon copy of the code found in the samples.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2, View.OnTouchListener {

private CameraView mCameraView;
private static final String TAG = "com.adilhz.logging";

private BaseLoaderCallback mBaseLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch(status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:

                Log.d(TAG,"Loaded OpenCV");

                mCameraView.enableView();
                mCameraView.setOnTouchListener(MainActivity.this);
                break;

            default:
                Log.d(TAG,"OpenCV"+status);
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
                break;

        }
    }
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mCameraView = (CameraView)findViewById(R.id.java_surface_view);
    mCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    mCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_9, this, mBaseLoaderCallback);
}
```

Could someone provide some pointers as to where I'm going wrong?

Thanks, Adil